# Increment inside while true loop doesnt work

Tags: python

```
x=0

def add(var):

    var+=1
    return var

while True:

    y = add(x)
    print(y)
```

This code gives output only as 1 for every iteration. But I need this code to increment the value, with the same code(architecture).

Comment: You always do `0 + 1`, because `x` doesn't change…

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
i = 1
def add(var):
    var+=1
    return var
    
while True:
  print(i)
  i = add(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this...

```
x=0 
def add(var): 
    var+=1 
    return var 
while True: 
    x = add(x) 
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def add(var):
    var+=1
    return var
x = 0
while True:
    y = add(x)
    print(x)
```

You can define `y` outside the loop, then add it to `y`

Or just do this:

```
y = 0
while True:
    print(y)
    y += 1
```

You can use a for-loop instead too.

```
for i in range(100): # whatever number you want to loop.
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

You keep passing x = 0, so it will always print 1. Try replacing x with y instead.

Comment: That'll get you an `UnboundLocalError`…